# Python regex alpha-numeric string with numeric part between two values

Tags: python, regex

I am terrible at regex in general, but I would be interested to know if there is a method to check if the numeric part of an alpha-numeric string is between two values, or less/greater than a certain value?

For example if I have a string to search in a file which has multiple numeric variations like below:

```
key_string (870 bytes)
key_string (1500 bytes)
key_string (70 bytes)
```

Is it possible to extract the 'key_string' string only on whether the '(xxxx bytes)' part is between a certain threshold, or less/greater than a certain value?

For example if I want to find all the above 'key_string' example where the second part is below 1200 bytes, can I print out:

```
key_string (870 bytes)
key_string (70 bytes)
```

and ignore the string below in one regular expression? :

```
key_string (1500 bytes)
```

Comment: It is possible, but is not encouraged. If you have numeric data, extract it, cast to an int, and compare to the threshold value, then take appropriate action to make everyone's life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.findall() to search along with regex.

**Explanation of regex as below:**

```
key_string\s+\((\d+)\s+bytes\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/H8MpT5EfCmy2_MaX)

**Code:**

```
import re

with open('result.txt') as fh:
    for l in fh:
        a = re.findall(r"key_string\s+\((\d+)\s+bytes\)",l.strip())
        if len(a) > 0 and int(a[0]) < 1200:
            print (l)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
key_string (870 bytes)

key_string (70 bytes)

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

**Code 2 as suggested by *@WiktorStribiżew* :**

```
import re

pattern = r'key_string\s+\((\d+)\s+bytes\)'
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
with open('result.txt') as fh:
    for match in regex.finditer(fh.read()):
        if int(match.group(1)) < 1200:
            print((match.group()))
```

Comment: I'd use `re.finditer` for this. You need to have an access to the whole match as well as the captured substrings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Added code. Please check. I have kept  both snippet for OP.

Comment: Yes, I see, the thing is I think it is a good idea to have code that will handle  multiple occurrences on a line.

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh Pundkar and Wiktor Stribiżew for your help, this is exactly what I was looking to do.  Much appreciated.